# Is PvP matchmaking done by Soul Level or Soul Memory in Dark Souls 2

Tags: dark-souls-2

What the title says.

I'm wandering because I saw a guy with Soul Greatsword while doing pvp at SL 40 and while it is (probably...) possible to get it at SL 40, it seems unlikely :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this wiki article about soul memory](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/soul+memory), only your soul *memory* affects matchmaking and summoning. So as long as both players have roughly the same soul memory, even if they are 700 soul *levels* apart, they can be matched against each others.

> Soul Level appears to have no effect on matchmaking in either NG or NG+ and thereafter.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the quoted "fextralife" wiki page contains some false information at this time, e.g. claiming that the Heirs of the Sun covenant would increase the memory range. For a more trustworthy and detailed explanation of soul memory visit the wikidot page: http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/online-matchmaking

Comment: @DominicDeCoco Community edited wikis will always have false information to some degree, but they are usually pretty accurate as far as public information is concerned; while a lot of people edit them, a lot of people review them as well. But thanks for the alternate source!